# How to include both single and double quotes in the same string variable in python

Tags: python

How can I include single and double quotes in the same string in python?

I know how to fix the problem if I am using only single quotes or double quotes. I am using the following code:

```
my_variable = """INSERT into 
mytable("UpperAndLowerCaseColumn","Second_Column") VALUES('''O'neal''', '''"The Film Title"''')""".encode("utf-8").decode('unicode_escape')

print(my_variable)
```

I get this in return:

```
'INSERT into mytable("UpperAndLowerCaseColumn","Second_Column") 
VALUES(\'\'\'O\'neal\'\'\', \'\'\'"The Film Title"\'\'\')'
```

What I need is this:

```
'INSERT into mytable("UpperAndLowerCaseColumn","Second_Column") 
VALUES('''O''neal''', '''"The Film Title"''')'
```

Comment: You get that on print? Or just typing variable into interactive prompt? It seems to print just fine as far as I can tell. In interactive session without print it will call `__repr__()` and not `__str__()`, so you'd see the escape character in it.

Comment: I am using pyspark with python 3 and psycopg2 to populate a postgres database. The problems is that when I execute the query in the string it contains the escape characters and therefore doesn't work on Postgres side. This means the string variable seems to hold the escape characters there, not just the interpreter on print.

Comment: It prints fine for me too and it doesn't contain any escape characters.

Comment: Does it print UpperAndLowerCaseColumn between double quote, O'neal between triple quotes and "The Film Title" between triple quotes?

Comment: [`INSERT into
mytable("UpperAndLowerCaseColumn","Second_Column") VALUES('''O'neal''', '''"The Film Title"''')`](https://onlinegdb.com/r1AqVzdHE)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
my_variable = """INSERT into mytable("UpperAndLowerCaseColumn","Second_Column")
VALUES(\'''O'neal\''', \'''"The Film Title"\''')""".encode("utf8").decode('unicode_escape')

print(my_variable)
```

Comment: How is that different from what I did?

Comment: I used \''' instead \'\'\' and went to next line before VALUES(...

Comment: Oh I see. It doesn't work. I get this:
    'INSERT into 
mytable("UpperAndLowerCaseColumn","Second_Column")\nVALUES(\'\'\'O\'neal\'\'\', \'\'\'"The Film Title"\'\'\')'

Comment: No idea. I get this from my code: INSERT into mytable("UpperAndLowerCaseColumn","Second_Column")
VALUES('''O'neal''', '''"The Film Title"''')

Comment: I'm sorry, I introduced a typo here when copying and pasting. This definitely works but now the question is, how can I introduce the escape character to a string that doesn't have it. Do you know how to do it? It's just because I am not declaring the variable manually.

Comment: let's say I want to generate that same string passing "UpperAndLowerCaseColumn","Second_Column", O''neal and "The Film" as variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`my_variable = '''INSERT into 
mytable("UpperAndLowerCaseColumn","Second_Column") VALUES('''O'neal''', "The Film Title")'''.encode("utf-8").decode('unicode_escape')`

Comment: Isn't that what I did?

Comment: `my_variable` doesn't include a triple quote to close the statement. Triple quotes would be `''' string '''.  Use this `my_variable = '''INSERT into 
mytable("UpperAndLowerCaseColumn","Second_Column") VALUES('''O'neal''', '''"The Film Title"''')""".encode("utf-8").decode('unicode_escape')''' `

Comment: Isn't that what I have?

Comment: It isn't, sorry, I see now. But the problem is that it is not generating what I need, which is this: 'INSERT into mytable("UpperAndLowerCaseColumn","Second_Column") 
VALUES('''O''neal''', '''"The Film Title"''')'

Comment: You have triple quotes after `film title` but not the end of the entire string.  I think that is why your expected result is cut short.

Comment: Try running this code, you'll see what I mean:
    table_name = "my_table"
values_to_insert = ["""O'neal""", '''"The Film "''']
column_name_list = ["UpperAndLowercase", "otherColumn"]

"INSERT INTO {} ".format(table_name) + ", ".join(['''"{}"'''.format(i) for i in column_name_list]) + "VALUES(" + ", ".join("""'''{}'''""".format(i).encode("utf-8").decode('unicode_escape') for i in values_to_insert)